# How do I specify include directories using NMake?

Tags: c++, nmake

I'm trying to use nmake to build the libfcg (http://www.fastcgi.com/), however I'm getting the following error:

```
..\include\fcgios.h(23) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
```

I have the Widows SDK installed and the Windows.h file is present in this directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include
```

How can I specify this as an include directory?

Comment: The first thing I would try is to run `nmake` from Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx/Visual Studio Command Prompt in Start menu - that gives most Windows SDK includes set as environment variable `include`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass -I"include dir" as command line option to cl.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this, is with the `INCLUDE` environment variable, example:

```
INCLUDE=C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um;C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories

Answer (score 2):

While using `nmake` you can specify the `cl.exe` include dir with an environment variable `CL`

```
set CL=/IC:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include
```